# Can I read a binary file and print out a text file in java?

Tags: java

I'm learning file I/O and I can read/write binary file from/to binary file , write text to binary file but I'm wondering can I read a binary file and print out a text , the content is the same when the binary file was created not the character by character?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can; if you've read byte array `byte[] bytes`, you can always convert it to String:

```
str = new String(bytes)
```

or

```
str = new String(bytes, "UTF-8")
```

and then

```
System.out.println(str)
```

But I think that doesn't make sense if the file is really binary.

Comment: I think there a misunderstanding.If I have a binary file, and I don't know its content because I can't see it by opening in notepad or another text editor, how can I read it by java?

Comment: Do you mean, how you would get this byte array?
So, for example, you can use just one nio method:
[Files.readAllBytes(path)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)), where path can be constructed by `Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/file");`